# Toggling is not working after integrating with Ajax call

Tags: jquery

On click of the combobox I am  doing a ajax call .

The toggling is working fine without the ajax call , please see this jsfiddle without the ajax call.

http://jsfiddle.net/KxXuM/28/

But when I integrated ajax for appending dynamic data to the combobox-options then toggling is not working

http://jsfiddle.net/KxXuM/27/

This is my code

```
(function($) {
  $('.combobox').on('click', '.txt-btn', function() {
    var ajaxcall = $.ajax({
      url: 'test',
      success: function(data) {
        alert('ajx call completed');
      }
    });
    ajaxcall.done(function() {
      $txtboxBtn = $(this);
      $comboboxOptions = $txtboxBtn.parent().next();
      $comboboxOptions.slideToggle();
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Could you please tell me how to resolve the issue ?

Comment: because your done function is never called as your ajax call is failing.

Comment: Your ajax request is failing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `this` inside your ajax done handler is nor referring to the element, it is referring to the `ajax` object.

You can use a closure variable to fix the problem

```
(function($) {
  $('.combobox').on('click', '.txt-btn', function() {
    var $txtboxBtn = $(this);
    var ajaxcall = $.ajax({
      url: '/echo/html/',
      success: function(data) {
        alert('ajx call completed');
      }
    });
    ajaxcall.done(function() {
      $comboboxOptions = $txtboxBtn.parent().next();
      $comboboxOptions.slideToggle();
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xct98hrr/)

Comment: Thank god , you are back in action for helping :))) ,

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
(function($) {
  $('.combobox').on('click', '.txt-btn', function() {
  var x=$(this);
    var ajaxcall = $.ajax({
      url: 'test',
      success: function(data) {
        alert('ajx call completed');
      }
    });
    ajaxcall.done(function() {
      $txtboxBtn = x;
      $comboboxOptions = $txtboxBtn.parent().next();
      $comboboxOptions.slideToggle();
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your toggling doesn't working because you miss scope and cannot accessw your element via `$(this)`, so to fix that problem you have to create variable with reference to `this`:

```
var me = this;
var ajaxcall = $.ajax({
// .....
```

And use that variable (`me`) instead of `this` within `ajaxcall.done` handler.

```
ajaxcall.done(function() {
  $txtboxBtn = $(me);
  // ....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgz5s0yo/